# Ansible variables scope clash

Tags: fedora, variable, ansible

I've got an [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) setup that looks like this

```
inventories/
    sandbox1
    group_vars/
       all
       sandbox1
pb/
    pb1/
        run_pb1.yml
```

I've got roles and other stuff too, but I think this is enough to capture the gist of what I need to do.

I've got a variable **foo** that I am defining inside **inventories/group_vars/all** AND **inventories/group_vars/sandbox1**

Now my issue is that whenever I call

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/sandbox1 pb/pb1/run_pb1.yml
```

The playbook is run with the value of **foo**
 that is contained in **inventories/group_vars/all**... put another way, foo is not being picked up from the **inventories/group_vars/sandbox1**

Is this the correct way to implement an inventory specific variable? I want to avoid creating mulitple playbooks for something as simple as a variable change... ie, I do not want to do something like this inside the "all" file

```
default_foo: bar
sandbox1_foo: baz
```

along with multiple playbooks, which would be the same except for the variable they reference.

Is there a way to do what I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

Host variables overriding group variables (see [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)) but you should define them in `/host_vars` directory. So eg using following setup:

```
.
├── group_vars
│   └── all.yml # foo: var_from_all
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   └── host1.yml # foo: var_from_host1
└── test.yml
```

You will get:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml 

PLAY [host1,host2] *************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "foo": "var_from_host1"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "foo": "var_from_all"
}
```